# How do I add columns based off a parameter in ssrs report

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, visual-studio-2019, ssrs-2017

I am creating a report on Visual Studio and I need to sum the columns based on the year. My data has number of packages for the year 2019 and 2020. I want a grand total for 2019 and for 2020 as the last column on my report. I try to sum it up , and it sums up 2019 and 2020 for my parameter and gives me that total. Any help here will be appreciated[image: Preview of my report]
[image: Excel view of how I want my total to be summed up]
[image: design view of my report]